# Four color theorem Java implementation of U.S. map

Tags: java, algorithm

I am attempting to assign a color to each of the states so that no two adjacent states share the same color (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem). The program will output each state and its color.

I'm reading in a text file with the following format for 48 states (2 aren't connected):

```
al,fl,ms,tn,ga
ar,la,tx,ok,mo,tn,ms
az,ca,nv,ut,nm
ca,az,nv,or
co,wy,ut,nm,ok,ks,ne
...
```

**Example:**

Alabama touches Florida, Mississippi, Tennessee, and Georgia.

Arkansas touches Louisiana, Texas, etc.

This is my code so far:

```
MapColor.java    

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MapColor {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ArrayList <String> statestemp = new ArrayList <String> ();
        ArrayList <State> states = new ArrayList <State> ();

        // read in each line
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("usa.txt"));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            statestemp.add(line);
        }
        reader.close();

        // create all state objects and adjacencies
        for (int i = 0; i < statestemp.size(); i++) {
            State st = new State();
            String[] str = statestemp.get(i).split(",");
            st.setName(str[0]);
            for (int j = 1; j < str.length; j++) {
                st.addAdj(str[j]);
            }
            states.add(st);
        }

        // set colors


        // print out states and adjacencies
        for (State s : states) {
            System.out.println("Name: " + s.getName());
            System.out.println("Color: " + s.getColor());
            System.out.print("Adj: ");
            s.getAdj();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

and

```
State.java

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class State {

    public String n = null;
    public int c = 0;
    public ArrayList <String> adj = new ArrayList <String> ();

    public String getName() {
        return n;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.n = name;
    }
    public int getColor() {
        return c;
    }
    public void setColor(int color) {
        this.c = color;
    }
    public void addAdj(String s) {
        this.adj.add(s);
    }
    public ArrayList <String> getAdj() {
        return this.adj;
    }
}
```

I am at the point where I would like to begin assigning colors, but I am unsure how to go about making comparisons.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: I suggest an informed deep-search on the field of the possible state->color functions.

Comment: This might be quite unorthodox but since the input is static the output can be part of the program. Thus you could solve your coloring by extracting colors from an existing [map](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a5/Map_of_USA_with_state_names.svg) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The four-color mapping algorithm is very complex, with 1476 special cases that you have to handle in your code.  If you can spare one more color, the five color mapping algorithm will meet your requirements, is much simpler, and there is a [nice writeup on it at devx.com](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/32927)

For the special case of a United States map, there are many states with less than five neighbors (e.g, Florida), so you only have to address the first case of the algorithm, which is this:

1. Convert the map to a graph (looks like you've done this or are close with your adjacency list)
2. Choose one node (state) on the graph with less than five neighbors and remove it from the graph.  This will reduce the complexity of your graph and may cause some nodes that previously had five or more neighbors to now have less than five.
3. Choose another node from the updated graph with less than five neighbors and remove it.
4. Continue until you've removed all the nodes from the graph.
5. Add the nodes back the graph in reverse order from which you removed them (think stack here).
6. Color the added node with a color that is not used by any of its current neighbors.
7. Continue until you've colored in the entire graph.

Answer (score 4):

I would make a queue of the available colors and iterate through each state assigning(ie dequeuing/enqueuing) colors as you go. THis is the basic idea behind greedy coloring: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_coloring. This probably won't be optimal but you only have 48 vertices (yes I m thinking of this as a graph).

Answer (score 0):

What you could do in this instance is make the State class so that it is self aware of how many states are around it, and what their colors are. This way you could make a method that checks whether any of the adjacent states have the same color (or whether that state has a valid color). This way you could then just loop through the states and check whether each state's color is valid.

Plus, this would allow you to implement a way to assess which color the states should be by asking all of the adjacent states for their colors, and then just assigning that state whatever color is not returned. You could start at one corner of the US and then work your way down in that fashion.

Hope that helps you with your problem!