# Four Color Theorem java solution

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, matrix, theorem

I'm trying to implement the four color theorem.  The four‐color theorem states that any map in a plane can be colored using four‐colors in such a way that regions sharing a common boundary (other than a single point) do not share the same color.  There is a map separated into regions and the regions are put into an adjacency matrix and by using four colors I'm trying to color the map so that no two contiguous regions share the same color. The adjacency matrix is used to encode which region borders on another region. The columns and rows of the matrix are the regions while the cells contain a 0 if the two regions are not adjacent and a 1 if they border.

**EDIT**
It has to be recursive

The adjacency matrix I am using is:

```
  A B C D
A 0 1 1 1
B 1 0 1 0
C 1 1 0 1
D 1 0 1 0
```

I am stuck on where to go from here.
Thanks for help in advance.

Heres my code:

```
public class FourColorTheorem
{
   public static int[][] nums = {{0,1,1,1},{1,0,1,0},{1,1,0,1},{1,0,1,0}};
   public static int[] states;
   public static int[][] border;
   public static int[] setNeighs;
   public static int[][] neighbors;
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      createStatesArray();
      printArray();
      if(tryColor(0))
         System.out.println("Works");
      else
         System.out.println("Did not color all");

   }

   public static int[][] checkNeighbors(int r)
   {
      border = new int[4][4];
      for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
      {
         if(nums[r][i] == 0)
            border[r][i] = -1;
         else
            border[r][i] = 1;
      }
      return border;
   }

   public static void setNeighbors(int r)
   {
      for(int x = r;x<4;x++)
      {
         setNeighs[x] = states[x+1];
      }
   }

   public static boolean tryColor(int row)
   {
      int p=0;
      boolean q = false;

      if(row>4)
         return true;

      if(states[row] == 0)
      {
         states[row] = 1;
         setNeighbors(row);
      }
      if(row>1)
         if(setNeighs[row] == setNeighs[row-1])
            return false;

      int[][] temp = checkNeighbors(row);

      return false;
   }

   public static void printArray()
   {
      for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
      {
         for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
         {
            System.out.print(nums[i][j]);
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
      addBorder();
   }

   public static void createStatesArray()
   {
      states=new int[4];
      setNeighs=new int[4];
      for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
      {
         states[i] = -1;
         System.out.print(states[i]);
      }
      System.out.println();
   }   


   public static void addBorder()
   {
      border = new int[4][4];
      for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
      {
         for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
         {
            if(nums[i][j] == 0)
               states[i] = 1;
         }
      }
   }


}
```

Comment: Have you run into a problem, or are you looking for general advice?

Comment: Primarily general advice, I don't know where to go from here to get the expected result.

Comment: Graph colouring is a big subject, and exact solutions are hard for many common classes of graphs, including many planar graphs, although there are some good heuristics that are used in practice. A Wikipedia starting point is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Algorithms.

Comment: I took a quick look at it and it makes some sense. Does the code I have make sense or is there a better more efficient way of writing it?

Comment: What _is_ the expected result?  If you only have four regions as you have in your example, any map coloring that assigns a different color to each region will be acceptable.  If you want the smallest number of colors, which is three in this example, that's a different problem, but you shouldn't call it a "four-color theorem" problem.

Comment: The expected result is:
`1`
`2`
`3`
`2`
And the goal is to have the smallest number of colors for a given map, which will vary but the test case at the moment is four regions.

Comment: You should look at this related question: [Four color theorem Java implementation of U.S. map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306116/four-color-theorem-java-implementation-of-u-s-map)